# Changing font in Listview without using extra adapter class

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I am not able to change the fonts of rows in a listview. I am not using extra adapter class and rows are populated statically. I am wondering how can I change fonts of rows. Below you can find my code for that.

```
public class Program extends Activity {

    private String[] gunler =
            {"Studio 1", "Studio 2", "Spinning", "Cross Fit"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_program);

        //(A) adımı
        ListView listemiz=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        //(B) adımı
        ArrayAdapter<String> veriAdaptoru=new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, gunler);

        final Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "futura-condensed-medium.ttf");

        //(C) adımı
        listemiz.setAdapter(veriAdaptoru);
        listemiz.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                    long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Program.this, ProgramDetail.class);
                int keyIdentifer = -1;
                intent.putExtra("kacinciGun", new  Integer(position+1).toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

and layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i don't think without custom adapter you can do this.

Comment: check if some other type than `android.R.id.text1` is there or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a custom TextView where you set the font there.

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    public void init(Context context) {
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "your font name here");
        setTypeface(typeface);
    }
}
```

Then create a new layout using this new textview

```
<com.your.package.CustomTextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Then in your activity create the adapter like so

```
ArrayAdapter<String> veriAdaptoru = new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (this, R.layout.some_layout, R.id.text, gunler);
```

Comment: not working unfortunately. throws an error at line         listemiz.setAdapter(veriAdaptoru);